# How to find min max values in Array - Scanner class

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I was trying to take user input, store the values in the Arrays, and then find min max values. My code works fine in case the array is initialized with values, but when I take user input it always returns 0 as min value. See the code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers in a set: ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int[] myArray = new int[number];
    int min = myArray[0];
    int max = myArray[0];
    
        
    System.out.println("Input your numbers: ");
    for(int i = 0; i <= myArray.length-1; i++) {
        myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        if (myArray[i] < min) {
            min = myArray[i];
        } else if (myArray[i] > max) {
        max = myArray[i];
        }
    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        System.out.println(max + " " + min);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

As a beginner, I'd appreciate your look at the above piece of code and hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {           
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          
    System.out.print("How many numbers in a set: ");
    
    int[] arr = new int[scan.nextInt()];                                                            
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                    
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;                    
                                                    
    System.out.print("Input your numbers: ");       
                                                    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {          
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();                    
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);                
        max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);                
    }                                               
                                                    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));       
    System.out.println(max + " " + min);            
    System.out.println();                           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you did this

```
int[] myArray = new int[number];
int min = myArray[0];
int max = myArray[0];
```

you set min and max on 0 and then, in for loop, you check if it is less than 0.
If you are giving only positive numbers to your program,min value will stay 0
If you want to find min and max value of array you can initialize min and max like this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code initializes min as 0 by default which is smaller most of the numbers we give in the array

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //maximum value Integer datatype can hold
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;// minimum value Integer datatype can hold
```

Here we make min as the heighest possible number and the max as the lowest possible number which makes the code mode bullet-proof to -ve values as well!.
to know more about Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE follow this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-max_value-and-integer-min_value-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

First of all `int[] myArray = new int[number];` initiates the array size. So if you input for example 4 which in this case is the `[number]`, you create an array `myArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};` .

Comment: That I've already known. I replaced 0 values with other values [i] in for loop. Anyway, I got good hints how to handle it, subject exhausted. thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Proximo_224: I think you could expand the answer a little bit and explain the reason why min is always 0. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```java
package javase.Arrays;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers in a set: ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int[] myArray = new int[number];
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;     
    
        
    System.out.println("Input your numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {          
        myArray[i] = scan.nextInt();                    
        min = Math.min(min, myArray[i]);                
        max = Math.max(max, myArray[i]);  
    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        System.out.println("Max : "+max + " " +"Min : " +min);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).